Change Swift dock icon at runtime
I'm trying to change SwiftUI app icon at runtime on macOS using the following code:
import SwiftUI

@main
struct projApp: App {
    init() {
        print("Initializing application...")

        let iconPath = "/Users/user/Documents/audio/vibe/desktop/src-tauri/icons/128x128.png"
        print("Attempting to load icon from path: \(iconPath)")

        if let customIcon = NSImage(byReferencingFile: iconPath) {
            print("Successfully loaded icon from path")
            
            // Set the dock icon using NSImage
            let image = customIcon
            let appDockTile = NSApplication.shared.dockTile
            appDockTile.contentView = NSImageView(image: image)
            appDockTile.display()
            
        } else {
            print("Failed to load icon from path: \(iconPath)")

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: iconPath) {
                print("File exists at path. Ensure it is a valid image.")
            } else {
                print("File does not exist at path. Verify the file path.")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

The icon is changed to invisible icon instead of the real icon:

How should I change it?
Icon used: https://github.com/thewh1teagle/vibe/blob/main/desktop/src-tauri/icons/128x128.png

using NSImage(contensOfFile:) instead of using byReferencingFile:, which is less common, I used contentsOfFile: which is more straightforward for loading an image from a file path and is appropriate for your use case.
rather than using contentView = NSImageView(image: image) I directly assigned the customIcon to the appDockTile.icon property, The icon property of the dock tile is the correct place to set the icon for the dock.
import SwiftUI

@main
struct projApp: App {
    init() {
        print("Initializing application...")

        let iconPath = "/Users/user/Documents/audio/vibe/desktop/src-tauri/icons/128x128.png"
        print("Attempting to load icon from path: \(iconPath)")

        if let customIcon = NSImage(contentsOfFile: iconPath) {
            print("Successfully loaded icon from path")
            
            // Set the dock icon using NSImage
            let appDockTile = NSApplication.shared.dockTile
            appDockTile.icon = customIcon
            appDockTile.display()
            
        } else {
            print("Failed to load icon from path: \(iconPath)")

            let fileManager = FileManager.default
            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: iconPath) {
                print("File exists at path. Ensure it is a valid image.")
            } else {
                print("File does not exist at path. Verify the file path.")
            }
        }
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


Value of type 'NSDockTile' has no member 'icon'
